# wp_nav_menu doesn't add current-menu-item when there is an url parameter

Tags: menus

`wp_nav_menu` doesn't add the `current-menu-item` CSS class when there is an url parameter in the url. Is there a way to ignore the url parameter?

Comment: URL parameter such as `www.domain.com/about/?test=true` because it should work. It's hard to tell what the problem is based on the information you've provided so I'd go through the steps of reverting to vanilla WordPress (disabled all plugins, remove customization, etc.) to figure out what's causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem: I used a 'link' menu item instead of a 'page' menu item because it was originally a post type archive (but I changed that in a page). If I use a 'page' menu item the `current-menu-item` CSS class does work when there is an url parameter in the url.

Comment: Wordpress Menu editor has archive item for each post type. First click on needed post type in accordion menu on the left side. Then select tab `All`. The first item in this list is solution.

Comment: Hello Remco! I don't understand, can you try to explain better how to fix the problem?